# HTML5 Video - Firefox stretches the video

Tags: css, html, firefox, video

I use HTML5 video as a video background, firefox stretches the video and sends a part of it out of browser chrome displays it all good. Here's the  [link](http://interim.mavsocial.com/) . Please check the video in chrome and firefox, firefox stretches the video out of the box and hides some part.

I've tried all over the internet to find if firefox has a different way of rendering video but could not find any solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see a difference between FF and Chrome, which versions are you using?

Comment: It's because of the `width="1920"`, set it to 100% with CSS and it should work

Comment: Firefox 35.0.1 - Chrome 40.0.2214.111.
The difference is very subtle the monitor in the slide background is not shows completely on firefox.